# What is the opposite of et seq.?

Tags: expressions, abbreviations, latin

What Latin-derived abbreviation could be used in place of "and the previous ones" or "and the predecessors" i.e., the opposite of et seq.?

I can't start from the other end and use et seq., because the context is a branching structure (could be a literal tree) where each branch point has only one *immediate* "predecessor" but may have many "successors." Therefore the concept of sequence applies to only one direction.

Example Sentence: "But let us consider the maternal line: Mary, Ana, [the word I am seeking would go here]." Note that "... Eve et. seq." does not have the same meaning because although a daughter has only one mother, a mother may have many daughters.

Comment: The question is contradictory: it asks about plural predecessors but then says there is only one... you wouldn't be trying to use Latin to make the tone of your work seem to be knowledgeable and important, would you? Use *le mot juste*, not what makes you seem clever.

Comment: There is no **established** short term (Latin or otherwise) for this kind of citing, because the need for it practically never arises. If you feel that it is really called for in this particular case (and perhaps you should reconsider whether it is), the best thing to do will probably be to fully spell out in English what you have in mind.

Comment: Can you provide an example sentence? Also: is this in math? Computer science?

Comment: (In computer science, I've never seen anyone use *et seq.* in this context either.)

Comment: There is a Latin SE for Latin questions.

Comment: @WeatherVane RE "contradictory"---sorry, I meant "only one _immediate_ predecessor." Post updated accordingly.

Comment: @alphabet2 RE "example sentnce:" I've appended one to the post.

Comment: @StuartF RE "Latin SE:" I don't think Latin SE is the place, since I want to use the phrase in a larger body of work that is English. My composition is not in Latin. I thought perhaps, like "et seq.", the phrase I am looking for might have been incorporated into English.